# Getting type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'error in JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Im sure you know the problem above. Im wondering how I can solve it. I understand that my data is in form of a list but inside the data class I used map. I don't really understand how I should change it to work, basically I just followed the flutter.dev [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

So if you are wondering what I did

I basically parsed my data with json_serializable. In testing with test data all worked fine.

My data:

My model contains a title, image & a nested class called modelData.

```
`import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import 'modelData.dart';


part 'Modell.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Modell {
  final String title;
  final String image;
  final ModelData modelData;

  Modell(this.title, this.image, this.modelData);

  factory Modell.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  => _$ModellFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ModellToJson(this);}
```

`

```
    import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';


part 'modelData.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class ModelData {
  final String title;

  ModelData(this.title);

  factory ModelData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  => _$ModelDataFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ModelDataToJson(this);
}
```

Im consuming the data with this code:

```
      var modelle = const[];

  Future loadDataList() async {
    String content = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/ddddddd.json");
    List collection = json.decode(content);
    List<Modell> _modelle = collection.map((json) => Modell.fromJson(json)).toList();

    setState(() {
      modelle = _modelle;
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    loadDataList();
    super.initState();
```

& if needed here a part of my Data:

```
   [
   {
      "title":" Alfa Romeo ",
      "image":" AlfaRomeo.png ",
      "modelData":[
         {
            "title":" 4C ",
            "variantenData":[
               
            ]
         },
```

I hope I wrote clear & detailed enough. If Im missing something, sry

**-----Update-----**

I tested a bit & found out that with simply adding List I no longer get the error, will test further to see whether the solution really works as intended

```
    import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import 'modelData.dart';


part 'Modell.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Modell {
  final String title;
  final String image;
  List <ModelData> modelData; //adding List

  Modell(this.title, this.image, this.modelData);

  factory Modell.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  => _$ModellFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ModellToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: `ModelData ` is an array not a `String` though from what I see

Comment: how do I have to change it so it works?

Answer (score 0):

You have parsed the data and all but the class named Modell should contain a list of ModelData and not a single ModelData. Please change the type to a list of ModelData and it should work hopefully.

````
class Modell {
  final String title;
  final String image;
  final List<ModelData> modelDataList;

  Modell(this.title, this.image, this.modelDataList);

  factory Modell.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  => _$ModellFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ModellToJson(this);}```
````

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work, If you click the link I sent you see that I have to write   final ModelData modelData;   when I am using nested classes

Comment: "modelData":[
         {
            "title":" 4C ",
            "variantenData":[
               
            ]. ModelData is clearly a list of Modell class right. How is it nested classes?

Comment: I think it is, because I have my class Model, in which I have the title & image, but inside each car brand object is another class, containing more specific data (model data), so its nested, maybe im committing an huge error, but I think its like that

Comment: But the json data which you have mentioned clearly shows an array of objects which contains title, image and a key named modelData which is an array of objects which contains title and varientData which is another array.

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```dart
  var modelle = const[];

  Future loadDataList() async {
    String content = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/ddddddd.json");
    List collection = json.decode(content);
    List<Modell> _modelle = collection.map((json) => Modell.fromJson(json)).toList();

    setState(() {
      modelle = _modelle;
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    loadDataList();
    super.initState();
```

More specific here:

```dart
List collection = json.decode(content);
```

If you go to [Flutter Example](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes) will see that `collection` will return a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Try change to:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> collection = json.decode(content);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for ur suggestion, I tried some things this morning and found a way to fix the error (not sure if I fixed it fully will test further), I updated the question, if you are interested you can see what worked for me